# different ways of consuming a REST API from java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

can you list down, what are the different ways to consume an REST API.
For Example : `RestTemplate`, `Web Client` etc.

Comment: Nobody knows all the frameworks out there, so that's an impossible question to answer. Do a web search for e.g. [`java consume rest api`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+consume+rest+api) and do your own **research** for what best fit your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Since you at least listed 2

**RestTemplate** - This is legacy way. Don't use it if you are on spring-boot 2.x.x

**Web Client** - This is the new Spring way for invoking webservices

From official Docs,

As of Spring 5.0, the non-blocking, reactive `org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient` offers a modern alternative to the `RestTemplate` with efficient support for both sync and async, as well as streaming scenarios. The `RestTemplate` **will be deprecated in a future version** and will not have major new features added going forward

There are other players like **OKHttp** or **retrofit** etc with each having it's own merit and demerit. Do your research and post specific questions